# I am trying to access my mysql server from the command line by typing in this: mysql -u root -p

Tags: mysql, cmd, server

I am trying to access my MySQL server from the command prompt. I typed in this command:

```
c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql -u root -p
```

Then I entered my password when prompted and got this error message:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I'm not too experienced with MySQL or the command line interface so I'm not sure what this error message means. I've tried watching some youtube videos on different ways to do this but I keep on getting the same error. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you initialized the database? Is the password valid? Have a look at this page in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-install-db.html

Answer (score 0):

It means your attempt to get authenticated failed.

That is probably because you are using the wrong password for the "root" user in your mysql instance. When you say "entered my password" do you mean you entered the password you set for root when you installed mysql, or do you mean the password you have for your user account on that computer?

It needs to be the mysql password for the user in mysql named "root". Note that this has nothing to do with any users in the operating system that is running this instance of mysql.

Check your choice of password and make sure you use the mysql "root" user password. Or if you have the credentials (that is, the user name and password) for a different user in the mysql instance, use those instead.